# Modify Code to Download File to Music Directory {Android}

Tags: java, android, cordova

Currently,The code below only saves downloaded files into the Download Directory on the phone storage.Hence the downloaded file cannot be accessed by other applications because it is private.

My Question is how do i modify the code i pasted below to save the files downloaded, into the Music Directory on the Sd card.
 I pasted the full code below:

```
    private void downloadFile() {
    new DownloadFileThread().start();

}
class DownloadFileThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                URL url = new URL(path);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                int length = conn.getContentLength();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                FileOutputStream fos = getOutStream(fileName);
                int count = 0;
                byte buf[] = new byte[1024];
                do {
                    int numread = is.read(buf);
                    count += numread;
                    progress = (int) (((float) count / length) * 100);
                    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DOWNLOAD);
                    if (numread <= 0) {
                        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(DOWNLOAD_FINISH);
                        break;
                    }
                    // 写入文件
                    fos.write(buf, 0, numread);
                } while (!cancelUpdate);
                fos.close();
                is.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        mDownloadDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
/**
 * @param fileName
 * @return
 * @throws FileNotFoundException
 */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("WorldReadableFiles")
private FileOutputStream getOutStream(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException{
    if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        String sdpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/";
        mSavePath = sdpath + "download";
        File file = new File(mSavePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
        }
        File saveFile = new File(mSavePath, fileName);
        return new FileOutputStream(saveFile);
    }else{
        mSavePath = mContext.getFilesDir().getPath();
        return mContext.openFileOutput(fileName , Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: And your question is ... ?

Comment: I just edited the question